# TypeScript: Function signature where the return type depends on an option argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that parses CSVs.  It stops parsing once it hits the first error:

```js
type Result<T, E> = {ok: true, value: T} | {ok: false, value: E};

function parseCsv(
    file: string,
    options: {trim?: boolean},
    parseLineFn: (line: Array<string>) => Result<null, string>,
): Result<null, string>;
```

Sometimes, callers want to get back a list of all errors instead of just the first one.  One option is to create another variant of `parseCsv` that returns `Result<null, Array<string>>`.

But I'm wondering if I can have just a single function, where a field in `options` changes the behavior.  I have an idea on how to implement the body of the function, but I'm not sure how to get the types right.

From the caller's perspective, I'm hoping for something like:

```
const result1: Result<null, string> = parseCsv(..., {}, ...);
const result2: Result<null, string> = parseCsv(..., {errors: single()}, ...);
const result3: Result<null, Array<string>> = parseCsv(..., {errors: multi()}, ...);
const result4: Result<null, Array<string>> = parseCsv(..., {errors: multi(10), ...); // Limit to 10 errors.
```

**Edit**: To be clear, I can achieve a basic version: [TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogTnA9nAwogNuiBjYyoC8UA5AM4CWAdgOZbFQA+JAtgK7rDnEDcAUL6EhQAShFLtgAHgAqAGlgA+QlADeiANYAuKMDisI8gG4BDdPu3SAvo1UbtAM1OkDUCAmTaYlvrwAmOdGM4aHtWSlxyREooMCDnFFJDSRgUVwAPYAhKX1JYd1QMLFxkBQAKbEKcPDhPFABKbVFxDklKdnR5eCQCzCrkUSkUhQUfQWgu5DRe4rgB5NSIDKycvO6pouqlIhT0zOzcsipaCHoAfihSXSOoWt3lg7YOLihzgEEEYxBJS7gjpW1KBBDG4fKFwpwolB7KU6qpeFAEVAKpRLlBgs1gABGRpiCStdryH5-ZSxODxRKlQ40Oh1PiIpFRVHoiQAJhxGPxmHk7zgn2+VxowxJcQgCUMlMenGItN4liAA)

But I can't figure out how to:

1. Get it to default to `single`.
2. Allow the error collector to be an interface that anybody can implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple function declarations:

```js
// for single 
function parseCsv(
  file: string,
  options: Options & {multipleErrors?: false},
  parseLineFn: (line: Array<string>) => Result<null, string>
): Result<null, string>;
// for multiple
function parseCsv(
  file: string,
  options: Options & {multipleErrors: true},
  parseLineFn: (line: Array<string>) => Result<null, string[]>
): Result<null, string[]>;

// actual implementation
function parseCsv(
    file: string,
    options: {trim?: boolean, multipleErrors?: boolean},
    parseLineFn: (line: Array<string>) => Result<null, string> | Result<null, string[]>,
): Result<null, string> | Result<null, string[]> {
  // ...
}
```

Now users of your function will get different return types depending on what they pass to `options.multipleErrors`. However, inside the function implementation you'll have to perform some typecasts, because compiler is not able to figure out connections between return type and option value.

Try it out at the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsAPAFQDRQKID4oBeKAbwHsBrALimACdEIcA3AQ2SdowF8oAfMlVoAzDvGZR2nCLVw8A3ACgloSFADyYYAEtyAO3jEySqHXo6AtgH5aAI3LlkENvqU8VAek9QR5elDwOvoA5s5QSiKI+gDGugZQYGz0EgDC8CwAFKa+Os608AzBIVg55Np6hrRa8YZQAGRklii6YM649PT+8La+4hA8pWZJKRAAMsEQAGL6tJnIk7QAgp1sIGiFFqH4AJTEhHBIqGj6KMg4m8X4Sju0hy0nZxdF28revv5Qzag6bRCR0TilUSyTSGWyZhEeVkgReJTKFQM8GqiLqjVI31a7U63VoDCYgxyIwkE3001mUHmiygK3oaw2cN2+1gCAep2Q51hWxCAG0ALrXW4so7odmcy6hfn4ZRKd5sOKIDhQKx-SwQfTANi1AGxWog0bpLI5SHQgpwoZmKDlWrIzSoozozG-bFdFK9BxOFz6QmW-UkyYzOYLMnLVbrCUhJlEA6s45i57cwiCe5xp5c4pS0pClOitMRpPCtl5uFSkxmYAACy6AHcoGL3F4fDnHhyExmBUoYkjgFBkgESMSIIbMgByEc4DEtZ0QDqu234gY4TJ7aNkSs1utnHg7WVN2O51vp7ad7tc4yD4djidOv6z3F9ZASQaUleEUjr8i1sXb3eF1OH-MT0MHtNgAJnPUEh3BK8yGfZdmXfKtP03DltyAA)